# I have fitted a GLM and failing to plot the model using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm

I have made a GLM and am trying to plot the model using ggplot using the following code. I think i need to add the type argument so that my model doesn't just produce a horizontal flat line. However i am struggling to fit it using the type argument as i run into this error message;

```
 Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = 
 object$xlevels) : 
 object is not a matrix
```

Here is my dataset and code used to get this if anyone knows the fix for this

my data (first 10 rows);

```
 aids
   cases quarter  date
 1      2       1 83.00
 2      6       2 83.25
 3     10       3 83.50
 4      8       4 83.75
 5     12       1 84.00
 6      9       2 84.25
 7     28       3 84.50
 8     28       4 84.75
 9     36       1 85.00
 10    32       2 85.25
```

my code used to create the model and plot

```
 model3 = glm(cases ~ date,
          data = aids,
          family = poisson(link='log'))


 #plotting the model (“link”, “response”, “terms”)
 plot_predictions <- function(model, type = 'response') {

   #make predictions
    preds <- predict(model, df)

   #plot
   df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(date, cases)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line(aes(date, preds), col = 'red') +
    ggtitle("Model 2 - Poisson GLM predicting cases") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 12, face = 'bold'))
 }

 plot_predictions(model3, aids)
```

dput output

```
dput(head(aids, 10))
structure(list(cases = c(2, 6, 10, 8, 12, 9, 28, 28, 36, 32), 
quarter = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), date = 
c(83, 
83.25, 83.5, 83.75, 84, 84.25, 84.5, 84.75, 85, 85.25)), 
row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please share the output of `dput(head(aids, 10))` so that we can load the example data in the same form you have it?

Comment: Sure, i have added it to the end of the question

Comment: The data frame `df` is not defined anywhere it's not defined in the environment (at least not in the code you've shown) and it's not an argument to the function you're creating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one that puts the predictions on the right scale:

```r
library(tidyverse)
aids <- structure(list(cases = c(2, 6, 10, 8, 12, 9, 28, 28, 36, 32), 
               quarter = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
                                     2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), date = 
                 c(83, 
                   83.25, 83.5, 83.75, 84, 84.25, 84.5, 84.75, 85, 85.25)), 
          row.names = c(NA, 
                        10L), class = "data.frame")
model3 = glm(cases ~ date,
             data = aids,
             family = poisson(link='log'))


plot_predictions <- function(model, df, type = 'response') {
  require(tidyverse)
  #make predictions
  preds <- predict(model, df, type= type)
  
  #plot
  df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(date, cases)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line(aes(date, preds), col = 'red') +
    ggtitle("Model 2 - Poisson GLM predicting cases") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 12, face = 'bold'))
}

plot_predictions(model3, aids)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

Here's how you could do it with confidence intervals, though this will only work nicely in bivariate models.  I've included an option using `ggpredict()` from the `ggeffects` package that will work in this and other circumstances.  The trick here is that you've got to make the predictions on the link scale, make the confidence intervals from the standard errors of the predictions and then transform everything (fit, lower and upper bounds) through the inverse link.

```r
library(tidyverse)
aids <- structure(list(cases = c(2, 6, 10, 8, 12, 9, 28, 28, 36, 32), 
                       quarter = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
                                             2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), date = 
                         c(83, 
                           83.25, 83.5, 83.75, 84, 84.25, 84.5, 84.75, 85, 85.25)), 
                  row.names = c(NA, 
                                10L), class = "data.frame")
model3 = glm(cases ~ date,
             data = aids,
             family = poisson(link='log'))


plot_predictions <- function(model, df, conf=.95, type = 'response') {
  require(tidyverse)
  #make predictions
  preds <- predict(model, df, type= "link", se.fit=TRUE)
  preds <- as.data.frame(preds[1:2])
  preds$x <- df$date
  preds <- preds %>% 
    mutate(lwr = fit - pnorm(1-(1-conf/2))*se.fit, 
           upr = fit + pnorm(1-(1-conf/2))*se.fit, 
           across(c(fit, lwr, upr), ~family(model)$linkinv(.x)))
  
  
  
  #plot
  ggplot(data=df, aes(date, cases)) +
    geom_ribbon(data=preds, aes(x=x, y=fit, ymin=lwr, ymax=upr), alpha=.25, fill="red", col="transparent") + 
    geom_line(data=preds, aes(x, fit), col = 'red') +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle("Model 2 - Poisson GLM predicting cases") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 12, face = 'bold'))
}

plot_predictions(model3, aids)
```

[image]

Here's the `ggpredict()` option:

```r
library(ggeffects)
g <- ggpredict(model3, terms="date [all]")
plot(g, rawdata=TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Brilliant. Do you know how easy it would be to add a 95% confidence interval for the mean to this?

Comment: @Joe I updated the answer to show how you could do this, but I also included a similar plot that you could make using the `ggeffects` package.  The `ggeffects` approach is almost certainly more robust, but writing your own function can have lots of pedagogical value.

Answer (score 4):

You are reinventing the wheel a bit here. This can be done automatically in ggplot using `geom_smooth`

```r
ggplot(aids, aes(date, cases)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(col = 'red', se= FALSE, method = glm,
                method.args = list(family = poisson(link = 'log'))) +
    ggtitle("Model 2 - Poisson GLM predicting cases") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 12, face = 'bold'))
```

[image]

You can even get the standard error to show by omitting `se = FALSE`:

```r
ggplot(aids, aes(date, cases)) +
    geom_segment(aes(xend = date, yend = 0), color = "deepskyblue4") +
    geom_point(size = 3) +
    geom_smooth(col = 'red3', fill = "red3", method = glm, alpha = 0.1,
                method.args = list(family = poisson(link = 'log'))) +
    ggtitle("Model 2 - Poisson GLM predicting cases") +
    theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = 'bold'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this using `broom::augment` to add the predictions of your model to the data and plot that:

```
model3 %>%
    broom::augment() %>%
    ggplot(aes(date, cases)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line(aes(date, exp(.fitted)), col = 'red') +
    ggtitle("Model 2 - Poisson GLM predicting cases") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 12, face = 'bold'))
```

[image]